# panic: sql: expected 0 arguments, got 1

Tags: mysql, sql, go

I am trying to execute queries with Go, but I cannot manage to request any query, because it keeps giving me the same error over and over.

I have changed the query multiple times, but that doesn't seem to help.
Also i have changed QueryRow in Query, unfortunately that doesn't help either.

```
func test123() {

    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "root:password@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/vitaintellectdb")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }

    id := 1
    var col string
    sqlStatement := `SELECT naam FROM medewerker WHERE naam="jansen"`
    row := db.QueryRow(sqlStatement, id)
    err2 := row.Scan(&col)
    if err2 != nil {
        if err2 == sql.ErrNoRows {
            fmt.Println("Zero rows found")
        } else {
            panic(err2)
        }
    }

}
```

QueryRow is designed to give you 1 row in return. Unfortunately the error is telling me that there should be no returns, I expect 1 row in return.

Comment: It’s saying you’re giving it one argument and the query doesn’t need any. Remove the `id` from the code since it’s not used

Comment: I tried that and it will remove the result, so i won't show my anything.

Comment: "the error is telling me that there should be no returns" -- No, that's not what the error says. The error says it expected 0 arguments, and you passed one. Don't pass any arguments.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The error is telling you that you are passing an argument to `QueryRow` that it is not expecting.

Your SQL statement doesn't have any placeholders so isn't expecting any but you are giving it one of `id`. Just change:

`row := db.QueryRow(sqlStatement, id)`

to:

`row := db.QueryRow(sqlStatement)`

Comment: I get the following error Unknown column 'jansen' in 'where clause'

Comment: That sounds like a different issue, namely your SQL syntax is incorrect.

Answer (score 4):

```
sqlStatement := `SELECT naam FROM medewerker WHERE naam="jansen"`
row := db.QueryRow(sqlStatement, id)
```

The given sql statement has no parameter. The following sql statement including the placeholder might work better.

```
sqlStatement := `SELECT naam FROM medewerker WHERE medewerkernummer =?`
row := db.QueryRow(sqlStatement, id)
```

Depending how your `id`-column is named you might have to change `naam=?` to `idColumn=?`. In the examples [here](https://golang.org/src/database/sql/example_test.go) you might find inspiration.

Comment: @JasonHayes123 are you sure there is a row with naam="your-given-id"? You can change it to `medewerkernummer=?`.

Comment: Id is I'm assuming the id column, not the name so it's highly unlikely someone will have a name of `1` which is what the above code now checks for

Comment: @fabian Where did you get medewerkernummer from?

Comment: @JasonHayes123 didn't know the name of the id column. So looked what is unique in your code. DB name in connect string (vitaintellectdb) sounded unique enough and a google search gave me besides this thread [a pastebin](https://pastebin.com/9AMsYnUk). Since you probably use one of the structures there, and structs often match column names it was an educated guess that's your id column.

Comment: @fabian Thanks a lot, this will help me out a lot!